# How does this OR if conditionals evaluate (python)

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I'm doing some custom reporting for a client of ours. I currently read in a csv and perform a number of operations to reduce the manual work on their end. I have this line of python code:

```
def review(row):
  if (1-(row['COST']/row['Competitor Price']) < .2) or row['NUM_SELL_THRU_PCT'] > 50 or row['NUM_WEEKS_OF_SUPPLY'] < 4:
    return 'N'
  else:
    return 'Y'
```

When I run the code, it ends up giving me a "Y" rather than an "N." In this specific example I'm reviewing, the 1-(cost/comp price) = .27, the sell thru is 0 and the WOS is 1.44. I would expect that if any of those conditions in the or statement were TRUE, it would return a 'N' in the row.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to provide a self-contained example with sample data illustrating the problem (i.e., include a sample value of `row` in your code).

Comment: Wild guess: You are using Python 2.x and `/` is doing integer division, leaving you with `0` instead of `0.27`

Comment: use `print row[...]` in the `else` block and see the values

Comment: Or could it be that `row['NUM_WEEKS_OF_SUPPLY']` is a string?

Comment: @tobias_k you were partly right, type was object. I converted to float - though, that's caused numbers in the NUM_WEEKS_OF_SUPPLY like 0.5, 0.45 and so on to be left blank in the row. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Kevin: Same thought: you need to provide a self-contained runnable example demonstrating the problem.